# Why won't the variable pass into jQuery.each?

Tags: jquery, variables

My code:

```
$('.colorPick').click(function(e) {
var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
var canvas2 = this.getContext('2d');
var data = canvas2.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
var rgb = 'rgb(' + data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2] + ')';
$('.colorPicker').each(function(rgb) {
    var x = this.width;
    var y = this.height;
    var canvas1 = this.getContext('2d');
    gradient1 = canvas1.createLinearGradient(0, 0, x, y);
    gradient1.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
    gradient1.addColorStop(0.5, rgb);
    gradient1.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
    canvas1.fillStyle = gradient1;
    canvas1.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);
});
}).disableSelection();
```

The variable **rgb** will not pass to the next .each function?

I am new to this if the answer is simple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're defining `rgb` as an argument to the anonymous function, hiding the parent scope's `rgb`. If you don't declare it as an argument, it will find the `rgb` from the parent scope (which is what I think you want):

```
// ...
var rgb = 'rgb(' + data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2] + ')';
$('.colorPicker').each(function() {
    // ...
```

Comment: oh ok simple as that, haha that had me stuck for half an hour! Thanks